# The code is correct but the logic is incorrect. how

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l = len(input("tell me your name!"))
if l > 18:
print("Please enter name with less than 18 letters")
else:
print(input("tell me your name!"))
```

#after getting the name as input, the length of the name with less than 18 letters have to be displayed else ask user to enter the name with less than 18 characters.

Comment: The code isn't correct actually: check the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need a while loop, that will ask a name until it satisfies the length constraint

```
name = input("tell me your name: ")
while len(name) >= 18:
    print("Please enter name with less than 18 letters")
    name = input("tell me your name: ")

print("Nice, your name is", name)
```

Comment: The code says <= 18 letters, but the error message says < 18 letters.  They can't both be right.